# Setting content-md5 on azure blob with nodejs?

Tags: node.js, azure

I have uploaded a file with nodejs

```
 sharedBlobSvc.createBlockBlobFromLocalFile(containerName, blobName, path, function (error, result, response) {
                    grunt.log.writeln("uploading '"+ path +"' -> '" + blobName+"'");
```

I dont seem to be able to find proper documentation and is googling these meethods as i find them. Anyone got a link? I am looking to find out if the content-md5 field is being set when using nodejs to upload the file. If not what is the corrent way with nodejs to set it ( i know how to calculate it).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check the code here: https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-node/blob/ce2faa9ec63d9f3d9b27e90c3b5fd56330aa2cc2/lib/services/blob/blobservice.js#L2971. As you can see, there's an additional parameter called `options` that you can pass to the method and there you can manually specify `contentMD5`. Also take a look at `storeBlobContentMD5` in options. By default it is set to `true` in case of block blobs.

> @param {bool} [options.storeBlobContentMD5] Specifies whether the
>   blob's ContentMD5 header should be set on uploads. The default value
>   is true for block blobs.

<del>Have you seen the code here: https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-node/blob/master/lib/services/legacyStorage/lib/blob/blobservice.js (especially [`putBlockBlobFromFile`](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-node/blob/master/lib/services/legacyStorage/lib/blob/blobservice.js#L884)). Basically along with the parameters you have specified, there's an additional `options` parameter where you can define additional parameters which includes `content-md5`. I have not used it myself, but looking at the options it seems that you can ask the SDK to compute MD5 for you - `options.setBlobContentMD5`:</del>

Comment: Wondering though, i am using createBlockBlobFromLocalFile in my js file and seems that there is no createBlockBlobFromLocalFile in the file you linked. Just wondering if I am using a different version of the sdk

Comment: https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-node/blob/master/README.md also indicate create and not put

Comment: I think this is the one instead. https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-node/blob/ce2faa9ec63d9f3d9b27e90c3b5fd56330aa2cc2/lib/services/blob/blobservice.js#L2971

Comment: Maybe you want to update your answer to include this also. Its default = true for block blobs

Comment: Seems there are two versions of the library. One that you included and one that I included. Let me check which one's the correct one.

Comment: I think that the legacy in the url of your link indicate that mine is newest :D

Comment: atleast its the one on npm

Comment: You're correct. I asked the same question to Azure storage team (i.e. which one to use) and they also told me the same. Will update my answer shortly.